# why can not I format a sql date?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

In the following code, I can not convert the date to the given format. why?

```
select sysdate,to_char('09/21/1990','ddth "of" mm yyyy') as formated
from emp;
```

error message:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: Hi, try this , you should be using a Date field to convert TO_CHAR , select sysdate,to_char(sysdate,'ddth' )|| 'of' || to_char(sysdate, 'mm yyyy') as formated from dual;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The to_char function is to convert a DATE type to a string.  Your date parameter is already a string.  If you really are executing the query with a string literal, you would have to convert it to a DATE type first, then to the string format you need, like this

```
select sysdate,
       to_char(to_date('09/21/1990','MM/DD/YYYY'),'ddth "of" mm yyyy')  as formated
from emp;
```